# Why is Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyChanged not firing?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, settings

I have the following in my user settings within a WPF MVVM app:

```
namespace MyApp.Properties {

    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "14.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public global::System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyApp.Models.MyItem> MyItems {
            get {
                return ((global::System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyApp.Models.MyItem>)(this["MyItems"]));
            }
            set {
                this["MyItems"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
        public string TestSetting {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["TestSetting"]));
            }
            set {
                this["TestSetting"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the value in `TestSetting` changes, the event `Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyChanged` is fired, however, when a `MyItem` within `MyItems` changes, this event is not fired.

How can I have this event fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object assigned to the property has to fire its own events on collection change, a common interface for that is `INotifyCollectionChanged` which is already implemented in `ObservableCollection<T>`. You should listen to the assignment of the property via `PropertyChanged` and then subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of the newly assigned collection.